# Domo dataset: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, pandas, domo

I have 64-bit Windows 10 OS and I recently updated my python using pip. I use pydomo to connect to DOMO dataset I created and while importing, it's giving the below error only sometimes. Here is part of the code and error.

```
import pandas as pd
from pydomo import Domo
domo = Domo(client_id,secret,api_host='api.domo.com')
#import dataset as pandas dataframe
DF = domo.ds_get('aaaaa-12ert34-3456789')


OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime
```

I was try to avoid it using the below command but didn't work.

```
np.iinfo(np.uint64).max
```

I saw someone use a CSV file to bring data and happened same error and avoid it using the below command.

```
csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
```

Is there anything like that for DOMO to avoid?

Any idea would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when I cannot get `ds_get` to work:

```py
domo.ds_query('aaaaa-12ert34-3456789', 'select * from table')
```